# What does this piece of java code do?

Tags: java

I came across this code in java and would like to know what it does.

```
public class Max <Key extends Comparable<Key>>{
  key[] pq; 
  ....
  ....
}
```

Comment: It defines a class... what exactly do you want to know? Maybe you want to learn about generics: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/

Comment: The declaration in the class should be `Key[] pq;` (with case matching the type parameter). As it is, this will not compile unless `key` is a type declared elsewhere.

Answer (score 4):

The above method defination says....

`public` **-** access modifier

`class`  **-** keyword to define a class

`Max`    **-** Name of the class

`<Key extends Comparable<Key>>` **-** This class is `Type Parametrized`, where the `Key` is an `Interface` that will **extends** `java.util.Comparable` Interface of type `Key`.

Also one thing to note here is `key[] pq`, i think if you have **Not** defined `key` anywhere, then it should be `Key[] pq`.

Answer (score 2):

The statement above defines the generic (or parameterized) type Max.

The parameter `Key extends Comparable<Key>` means that the parameter may be only an interface that extends an interface `java.lang.Comparable`.

May it be clearer for you, `Key extends Comparable<Key>` is equivalent to `T extends Comparable<T>`

You may want to explore it further by looking at [this link](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html#FAQ001)