# Implementation of comparable interface(Java) in Binary heaps program in algorithms course by Princeton Univeristy

Tags: java, algorithm, interface, comparable, binary-heap

I don't use extensive Java for programming and therefore just have basic knowledge about the language. I'm doing [an algorithm course on coursera](https://www.coursera.org/learn/algorithms-part1/).

The program for the binary heap given in this course is:

```
public class MaxPQ<Key extends Comparable<Key>>
{
    private Key[] pq;
    private int N;


    public MaxPQ(int capacity)
    { pq = (Key[]) new Comparable(capacity + 1);
    }
    public boolean isEmpty()
    { return N==0;}
    public void insert(Key key)
    { pq[++N] = x;
      swim(N);}
    private void swim(int k)
    {  while(k>1 && less(k/2,k))
       {
            exch(k,k/2);
            k=k/2;
       }
    }
    public key delMax()
    {
         Key max = pq[1];
         exch(1,N--);
         sink(1);
         pq[N+1] = null; //To prevent loitering.
         return max;
    }
    private void sink(int k)
    {
         while(2*k<=N){
            int j= 2*k;
            if(j<N && less(j,j+1))j++;
            if(!less(k,j)) break;
            exch(k,j);
            k=j;}
    }
    private boolean less(int i, int j)
    { return pq[i].compareTo(pq[j])>0; }
    private void exch(int i, int j)
    { Key t = pq[i]; pq[i] = pq[j]; pq[j] = t; }
```

`compareTo()` method will be defined in the definition of the `Key` class, when it overrides the default method `compareTo` in a comparable interface.

Now, I understand that comparable is an in-built interface in `java.lang`.
While defining the `MaxPQ` class, the generic type used is:

```
public class MaxPQ < Key extends Comparable < Key > >
```

Since `Comparable` is an interface, and `Key` extends that interface, that means that `key` will have to be an interface as well.

Now I don't understand how this works.

Could someone please explain to me what good it would do if an interface would act as a generic type, and why `Key` needs to extend `Comparable<Key>`.

It would be really helpful if you could also give me an example an how `Key` might be defined (using `Comparable` interfaces).

Comment: just use `Integer` to have a try

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12659710/what-does-this-piece-of-java-code-do

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does this piece of java code do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12659710/what-does-this-piece-of-java-code-do)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are missing is understanding

```
<Key extends Comparable<Key>>
```

That doesn't mean that Key is interface... It means that Key is a subclass of Comparable and can be treated as such.

```
Comparable<Key> c = new Key();
```

In the end it doesn't matter if Key implements an interface Comparable, or extends a class Comparable, because in both cases it can act as Comparable - and has the methods that Comparable has.

Comment: Okay, so if Key is a sub-class of Comparable, that means Comparable is a user-defined class and not the pre-defined Comparable interface in java.lang. Is that what you're saying?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12659729/5961353  This answer says that key is also an interface.

Comment: `Key` is some type that implements `java.lang.Comparable<Key>`. I'd say the answer you cite is misleading.

Comment: I think that what they meant in that answer is that you can treat `Key` as either `Comparable<Key>` or some other interface that extends it. Although when instantiating `MaxPQ` you can pass whatever type that is a subtype of `Comparable<Key>`.

Comment: In short, that answer (stackoverflow.com/a/12659729/5961353) is quite bad.

Comment: I agree with @ciamej - that answer is misleading. I guess mine was too, there is nothing to stop you from passing interface as parameter (certainly not from compiler point of view) - my main point was that extends in no way means that key IS for certain an interface.

Comment: You need to mention that the Comparable is an interface ! it can't be extended from class!

Answer (score 1):

`Key extends Comparable < Key >` means only that `Key` implements interface `Comparable < Key >`. Nothing more.

Comment: In that case, won't we have to use the keyword 'implements' in place of extends?

Comment: Well, I agree that the syntax might be misleading, but it is how it is. You use `extends` vs `implements` in class declaration, but use only `extends` in generic type declaration. Probably because if you have a more generic case like `U extends V` where `V` itself is some other generic type we don't know much about, then it would be difficult to differentiate between interface `V` and class `V`. In other words `extends` is more "generic" ;)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20390978)

Comment: @SRack could you please elaborate on why this is not an answer to the OP's question? The OP wrote: "Since Comparable is an interface, and Key extends that interface, that means that key will have to be an interface as well. Now I dont understand how this work.". Clearly, there was a misunderstanding on the OP's side which my answer addresses. The rest of the question is based on a false premise, e.g.: "what good would an interface do as a generic type, and why Key needs to extend Comparable" and "how Key might be defined(using Comparable interfaces)", which becomes non-sensical.

Comment: Also irregardless of if this answer is correct or not, I want to add the fact that wrong answers are not supposed to be flagged and deleted as NAA, but downvoted. This is an answer by any standard. Right or wrong? Not the reviewer's job to assess. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/20390978)

Comment: Personally speaking, I saw this in the review and thought it better suited to a comment. The extra context provided in the accepted answer makes the difference IMHO. There's always going to be an element of subjectivity in these reviews, though someone has flagged this and the review is currently two to one against the answer. There's nothing personal in my decision, and this is the reason reviews require multiple viewpoints - perhaps I'm just mistaken with this one. Apologies if so @ciamej.